# How to Run Rational Team Concert on Mac OS X

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, rational-team-concert

I have a doubt that what is  Rational Team Concert and how to install the  Rational Team Concert on Mac OS X. I searched so many links to understand this but I didn't understand. 
a) Does this supports Mac OS x
b)How to install it and what are the steps to follow.

Please help me to do and Please provide me the associated tutorial to this.

Thanks In Advance..

Answer (score 0):

a) Yes. Mac is supported.(via eclipse)

b) Install eclipse and use RTC as a plugin.

You can get the plugin version of RTC by search for "p2 Install Repository" in RTC download page.

Answer (score 0):

Mac is supported on client side (eclipse). Other than the plugin version mentioned before, there is also a standalone version for MacOS, that you can download from jazz.net